# How to evaluate $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-3/2}\,d\theta$, where $a>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral? $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-3/2}\,d\theta,$$where $a>0$

Comment: I would write $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin^2 \theta +a}} = \frac{\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2 \theta +a}}$$ and try to manipulate

Comment: I would either use complex analysis (after writing it as $\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{2\pi} (\sin^2\theta + a)^{-3/2} \,d\theta$ so it's an integral over a full period), or try the Weierstrass substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(\sin^2\theta+a)\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+a}} \,d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{a(\frac{1}{a}\sin^2\theta+1)\sqrt{a\left( \frac{1}{a}\sin^2\theta+1\right) }} \,d\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{a}\sin^2\theta+1)\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}\sin^2\theta+1}} \,d\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1+a^{-1}\sin^2\theta)\sqrt{1+a^{-1}\sin^2\theta}} \,d\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1 - (-a^{-1})\sin^2\theta)\sqrt{1 - (-a^{-1})\sin^2\theta}} \,d\theta}_{\Pi(-a^{-1}\,|\,-a^{-1})}$$

Also

> **Solution I**
>   $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,d\theta = \frac{\Pi\left(-a^{-1}\,|\,-a^{-1}\right)}{a\sqrt{a}}\, $$
>   [*For more information*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(EllipticPi%5B-(1%2Fa),-(1%2Fa)%5D)%2F(a*%5Csqrt%7Ba%7D))

Where $\Pi\left(-a^{-1}\,|\,-a^{-1}\right)$ ist [*The Complete Elliptic Integral of the Third Kind*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheThirdKind.html)
$$\Pi\left( n\,|\,m\right)  = \Pi\left( n;\,\frac{\pi}{2}\,|\,m\right)  = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\left( 1 - n\sin^2(t)\right) \sqrt{1 - m\sin^2(t)}} \,dt$$

The integral is also allowed to be expressed in terms of [*The Complete Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind*](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/introductions/CompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html) $E(m)$

$$E(m) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 - m\sin^2(t)}\, dt$$

There the complete elliptic integral of the second kind satisfies [*the imaginary modulus identity*](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E5):
$$E(-m)=\sqrt{1+m}\,\,E\left(\frac{m}{1+m}\right)$$
Where 
\begin{align*}
E\left( \frac{m}{m+1}\right)  &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{m}{m+1}\right)\sin^2(t)}\, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{m + 1 -m\sin^2(t)}\, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + m\cos^2(t)}\, dt
\end{align*}
Changing variables to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - t,\, dt = -d\theta,\implies \cos(t) = \sin\theta$, with $\theta$ going now from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $0$, then reversing the path of integration and changing the sign on the integral, therefore
$$E\left( \frac{m}{m+1}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + m\sin^2\theta }\, d\theta$$

In this way we can write the integral as follows
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,d\theta$$
$$\frac{1}{a\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{a}\sin^2\theta+1)\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}\sin^2\theta+1}} \,d\theta$$
Set $k = \frac{1}{a} $
$$\frac{k}{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(k\sin^2\theta+1)\sqrt{k\sin^2\theta+1}} \,d\theta$$
$$\frac{k}{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{(k\sin^2\theta+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,d\theta$$

$\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}(\sqrt{1 + a\sin^2\theta})$
$= \frac{-a+2a\sin^2\theta + k^2\sin^4\theta}{(1 + k\sin^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
$= \frac{-a-1+1+2a\sin^2\theta + k^2\sin^4\theta}{(1 + k\sin^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
$= \frac{-(a+1)+ (1 + a\sin^2\theta)^2}{(1 + k\sin^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$
$= \frac{a+1}{(1 + k\sin^2\theta)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-\sqrt{1+a\sin^2\theta}$

$$\frac{1}{k + 1}\left[ \frac{k}{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + k\sin^2\theta} -  \frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}(\sqrt{1 + a\sin^2\theta}) \right]\,d\theta$$
$$\frac{1}{k + 1}\left[ \frac{k}{\sqrt{a}}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1 + k\sin^2\theta}\, d\theta}_{E(-k)} - \left(\frac{k\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{k\sin^2\theta+1}}\bigg\vert_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\right)  \right]$$
$$\frac{1}{k+1}\left[\frac{k}{\sqrt{a}}E(-k) - (0 - 0)\right]$$
$$\frac{k}{(k+1)\sqrt{a}}E(-k)$$
Go to back $k$
$$\frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{a}+1\right)a^{\frac{3}{2}}}E(-a^{-1})$$
$$\frac{1}{\left( \frac{1}{a}+1\right)a^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{1+a^{-1}}E\left( \frac{a^{-1}}{1+a^{-1}}\right)$$

> **Solution II**
>   $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin^2\theta+a)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,d\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{a}+1}\,a^{\frac{3}{2}}}E\left( \frac{1}{a + 1}\right)$$[For more Information](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%20pi%2F2%20of%201%2F(a%20%2B%20sin%5E2(x))%5E(3%2F2)%20with%20respect%20to%20x)

Many important applications of these integrals were found at that time.\
The problem of evaluating such integrals was converted into the problem of evaluating only three basic integrals, namely the incomplete elliptic integrals of the first, second, and third kinds—  $F(z|m),\, E(z|m)$, and $\Pi(n;z|m)$  (A. M. Legendre). See [Introduction to the incomplete elliptic integrals](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/introductions/IncompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html)

Here are some interesting links:
1- [Definition of Elliptic Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html)
2- [Introduction to the complete elliptic integrals](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/introductions/CompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html)
3- [Compute $\Pi\left(n|m\right)$](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticPi.html)
4- [Elliptic Integrals](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19)

Comment: I ran a numerical integration for $a = 0.3$, the result is ``3.50469``. Your solution is ``2.92353``

Comment: @caverac How did you came to `3.50469` ?

Comment: Wolfram gives no result :(

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cpi%2F2%7D(%5Csin%5E2(x)%2B(0.3))%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%7D+dx

Comment: Standard computation time exceeded...

Comment: Mathematica's NIntegrate gives $3.50469$ for $a=0.3$.

Comment: Among other things, you replace $\cos\theta$ with $\cos 0$ at some point. That looks not correct.

Comment: You're right, I look again. Maybe I can solve the error, before removing all.
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: ``import scipy.integrate as integrate``

``import numpy as np``


``print integrate.quad(lambda x: (np.sin(x)**2 + 0.3)**(-1.5), 0, 0.5 * np.pi)``

Comment: I have completely reworked my answer. Now for $a=0.3$ gives 
$\frac{\Pi\left(-0.3^{-1}\,|\,-0.3^{-1}\right)}{0.3\sqrt{0.3}} = 3.50469$

Comment: @junjiema2 You should click on "accept this answer", in case it has solved your problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

With Mathematica notation we have that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a+\sin^2\theta}}$ is an elliptic integral, namely
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a}}\,K\left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right) $$
hence by differentiating with respect to $a$ we get that
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(a+\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{a\sqrt{a+1}}\,E\left(\frac{1}{1+a}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jack. Does your result imply that this integral can't be expressed by more elementary functions?

Comment: @junjiema2: I am afraid it cannot (at least for generic values of $a$).